# Disprove existence of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove/disprove that exists a linear transformation $S$

$$
S: (Z_5)^2 \to (Z_5)^3
$$

such that:

$$
S(1,4) = S(2,3) = (2,3,4)
$$
$$
S(4,4) = (1,0,1)
$$

The answers says it is wrong, but im not confident with the answers.

Why cant i say that $S(0,0) = 0$

Why it is contradict for example the linear expantion theorem?

How do you prove/disprove this?

Thanks.

Comment: I dont understand what you ask

Answer (score 3):

Assume, for a contradiction, that $S$ is linear. Then
$$S(0,0)=S((1,4)+2(2,3))=S(1,4)+2S(2,3)=(2,3,4)+2(2,3,4)\ne (0,0,0).$$

Answer (score 0):

As $2\cdot(1,4)=(2,3)$ but $2\cdot(2,3,4)\neq(2,3,4)$ we can't even have $S(1,4) = S(2,3) = (2,3,4)$.